# Is it better to make 2 API calls and discard 1, or call one at a time when inside cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda

I know that cloud functions charge money based on execution time and network costs.

I am writing a cloud function that calls 2 external APIs to authenticate a user. Both external APIs just return a single boolean and therefore don't send much info.

Which technique is better overall?

1. Make both external API calls using `fetch()` at the **same time** knowing that 1 may be useless half the time.
2. Make the external API call **one after the other**, and not make the second one if not needed.

I'm thinking doing #1 will shorten the "wall time" of my cloud function and therefore may be cheaper? But I make more external calls which may be expensive?

But doing #2 will make the cloud function stay in memory for longer and therefore more "wall time".

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 results in more complex code as you will need to wait for both fetches to complete unless you like container crashes to debug.

Method 2 is simpler to implement and debug but could result in longer wall clock time.

You will need to decide which method is better when you factor development time, debugging time, analyzing errors in logfiles, and execution time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I complete the response using only data from the 1st fetch and ignore the 2nd fetch and let it time out (or manually call abort with `AbortSignal`, would it still cause a container crash or unecessary debug texts? And if I leave the 2nd fetch hanging (even though I've completed the response) does that unfulfilled fetch linger and still count towards my wall time?

Comment: @KernelJames - When you initiate two fetches and one completes and then your function returns to the client, there is still a thread running that has not been completed. That will cause an exception which will be logged (usually). That is why I said your code will be more complex or you will spend more time reading log files. Anytime you have multiple asynchronous paths in your code, complexity goes up and stability/testability goes down. Complex is not a good design pattern for services such as Cloud Functions. Keep it Simple.